# Quando escrevo na div ela sai do lugar

Tags: html, css

```css
#meio {

  width: 100%;

  text-align: center;

}

.box {

  margin: 10px 4px;

  margin-bottom: -4px;

  display: inline-block;

}

#box-1 {

  width: 290px;

  height: 300px;

  background-color: white;

}

#box-2 {

  width: 290px;

  height: 300px;

  background-color: white;

}

#box-3 {

  width: 290px;

  height: 300px;

  background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="meio">

  <div id="box-1" class="box">aaaaa</div>

  <div id="box-2" class="box"></div>

  <div id="box-3" class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acrescente um "display: flex" em seu id #meio. Ai você pode até retirar o "display:inline-block" da classe .box

```
#meio {

  width: 100%;

  text-align: center;

  display: flex;
}

.box {

  margin: 10px 4px;

  margin-bottom: -4px;

}
```